# QGIS 2.18 - How to reference a svg symbol which is in the qml file's directory?

Tags: qgis, svg, file-path, qml

Relative path for svg symbols in .qml files works as expected if the svg file **is in another directory** than the .qml file's.
Example :

```
<prop k="name" v="../icons/symbol.svg"/>
```

However, if the svg file **is in the same directory** as the .qml file, it doesn't.
I tried with this syntax :

```
<prop k="name" v="symbol.svg"/>
```

And this one :

```
<prop k="name" v="./symbol.svg"/>
```

With no success...
Is it a bug or do I miss something ?

Answer (score 3):

The QML location is irrelevant. Once you have selected the qml file to apply it to a layer in your project, its information is "copied" to the project file - which is likely somewhere else.

SVG paths in the QML file are relative to the path you have declared in QGIS options. You can add a new path pointing to the folder holding the qml + svg if you want.

[image: svg paths]

Comment: The context being a plugin, I could indeed add programatically the path to qml and svg files.
But I still don't understand why relative paths work in the case of a different directory (which indeed appears in the svg symbol path in the layer's properties dialog).

Comment: @sigeal Probably because the relative path, from one of the declared svg folder, match the one in your QML. (ex: svg folder = c:\svg\, your file is in c:\icons\, so "../icons" means "start from c:\svg\, go up to c:, go down to c:\icons " and it finds your svg there.)

Comment: I checked that but it is not the case...
The other workaround I found so far is to update svg path in the qml file when the plugin is loaded.